# SIGINT with getchar()

Tags: c, signals, sigint

I'm new to C and am attempting to write a minishell program that should stop the child process (as a result of a fork to run exec) or jump back to the start of the loop (print out [currentdir/]> and wait for input) as soon as I run into a SIGINT.
Currently, I have to hit enter after ^C in order for the SIGINT to be processed, but ideally, I should not have to.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
volatile sig_atomic_t interrupted = 0; //interrupted is originally set to false.

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    interrupted = 1;
    //printf("\n");
}

int main_helper()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot register signal handler. %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    
    /* code to get current directory and print it in the format [dir/]> */

    while (is_exit == 0) //because no booleans
    {
        /*
            getting user input.
        */
        input_str = malloc(sizeof(char)); //starting out w a str of length 1.

        if (input_str == NULL)
        { //if the malloc fails for some reason.
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc() failed. %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }

        int c; //the character that we're at
        int i = 0;
        //read chars until null term or eof found
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
            if (c == EOF)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to read from stdin. %s.\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }
            input_str[i++] = c;
            input_str = realloc(input_str, i + 1); //adding space for another

            if (input_str == NULL)
            { //if it can't realloc for some reason.
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: realloc() failed. %s.\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        input_str[i] = '\0'; //adding null terminator at the end.
        
        /*
            dealing with the input using exec or built-in functions
        */

        free(input_str); //free the input that we just realloced stuff for

        interrupted = 0;

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, I'm not completely sure why exactly this is happening, but if I'm understanding some other StackOverflow threads correctly, the `getchar()` function may blocking the SIGINT until after enter is pressed. Does anyone know how to fix this? Would using `setjmp`/`longjmp` help? How would I implement these if they could solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `SIGINT`, but you can write a non-blocking `getchar` using `fread`.

```c
unsigned char buffer;
while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, stdin) == 0) {
    // Check signal in here
    
    // If no character was read, check if it was due to EOF or an error
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        // We reached the end of the file
    }

    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        // An error occurred when we tried to read from stdin
    }
}
```